# Easy_install script for Python 3

Tags: windows, python, easy-install

I came across this nifty little piece of software: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools to install Python packages on Windows. However, this only supports till Python 2.7. Is there an equivalent tool for Python 3? Or is Python 3 still in beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute

This is supposed to be the new setuptools.

Edit:

Well most python packages come with `setup.py` which make use of distutils commands:

```
python setup.py install
```

This installs the packages to the python version used to run this command.

Also pip is usefull for installation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

so First you install the distribute.

- Download the source from the link i provided
- Unpack
- Run setup.py as shown above, with the python you wish to install it to. If you only have one python. plain `python setup.py install` will do.
- Then download pip from the link
- unpack
- run setup

Now you can install python packages found in pypi, with command :

```
pip install packagename
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use it to install Python 3 packages on Windows. Can you help me?

Comment: Added more info

Comment: I have Python 2 and 3. So I should run setup.py from the Python 3 folder correct?

Comment: yes e.g `c:\Python33\python.exe setup.py install`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I wish I could upvote you more than once! A lot of work was saved for me